# Shopify JWT session token expired while making axios request call

Tags: laravel, vue.js, jwt, shopify, shopify-app

I have created an app on `laravel` and `vue.js` and for the authentication process, I have used the [laravel-shopify](https://github.com/gnikyt/laravel-shopify) package. right now when the Axios call duration is long that time gets a session token expired error. I have already referred this solution but this was not worked for me.

1. [Shopify App-bridge session token is having some issues while working with the vue.js and Axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70244806/shopify-app-bridge-session-token-is-having-some-issues-while-working-with-the-vu)

Please check attached documents, please check.

[image]

video:- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1US2dzgcPWm6iQcK4SMS4b6q85q9l89Mx/view?usp=sharing

When I have passed many files to Axios, I don't want to get expire token error. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just request a new session token before each axios request? See: https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/app-bridge-jwt-token-expires-after-1-minute/td-p/1188070

Comment: @policenauts Should I have to store in `config.headers.Authorization` every time before making an Axios call? because before Axios calls I have consoled the session token and gotten new session tokens every time. Please replay ASAP